# How to stagger linked duplicate grease pencil animations?

Tags: animation, modifiers, keyframes, grease-pencil, dopesheet

I don't know the term for this as I can't find what I am looking for through googling.

I have a grease pencil object with a frame by frame animation. I have created a linked duplicate, as I want the frame by frame animation to be the same. However, I want the objects to play one after another rather than at the same time. Is there a way to make this happen, or are the always linked to play at the same time?

The closest thing I've found is using Time Offset modifier with "Fixed Frame" and setting keyframes for the frame property along the timeline. It seems ok, but I'll have to adjust each duplicate if I ever extend the number of frames in the original. Is there a better way?

Screenshots as an example per the comment request:
[image: Blend screenshot]

The screenshot shows 3 spikes. The original and two copies. I want them to animate one after the other but still be linked. I have not been able to figure out how to adjust where on the timeline they animate without affecting all of them. I am used to other programs where you can move the object along the timeline to dictate when and where it shows up.

This is the modifier I have that works to delay when the object animates, but I have to manually set it for each object.
[image: Time Offset modifier]

Comment: Hello, could you share a screenshot?

Comment: I have updated the post with screenshots.